# controlling a servo with iphone breakout board

Tags: iphone, coronasdk

I'm new to Stack Overflow and programming in general, I hope you don't mind my questions. I ordered a breakboard for my iphone and it comes with all 30 pin assignments. I want to write an app that will allow me to control a servo motor and a sensor using the iphone. I am currently learning to program with the corona SDK and I was wondering if I could just use that to write my app. I looked up the specs and the iphone can handle multi threading so this should be just as good if not better at handling input then an Arduino microprocessor. Basically I am just wondering if Corona SDK which uses lua as a programming environment could do this. Thanks in advance.
SM

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do this corona, you'll have to use the native obj-c/cocoa apis.

You'll have to look at the External Accessories framework. Note that generally you have to have an MFi account in order to ship apps that connect to accessories that use the dock connector.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/_index.html